# All elements before last comma in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, split

How can i get all elements before comma(,) in a string in c#?
For e.g.
if my string is say

```
string s = "a,b,c,d";
```

then I want all the element before d i.e. before the last comma.So my new string shout look like

```
string new_string = "a,b,c";
```

I have tried split but with that i can only one particular element at a time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
string new_string = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf(','));
```

Comment: Beware that this will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception when the original string doesn't contain a comma! So make sure to check whether the last index isn't -1 or if you want to keep a single comma, whether it's greater than 0.

Answer (score 7):

If you want everything before the *last* occurrence, use:

```
int lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf(',');
if (lastIndex == -1)
{
    // Handle case with no commas
}
else
{
    string beforeLastIndex = input.Substring(0, lastIndex);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the follwoing regex: `"(.*),"`

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("(.*),");
string s = "a,b,c,d";

Console.WriteLine(rgx.Match(s).Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
string s = "a,b,c,d";
string[] strArr = s.Split(',');

Array.Resize(strArr, Math.Max(strArr.Length - 1, 1))

string truncatedS = string.join(",", strArr);
```